# Why Toc is in counting but doesn´t appear as title in page?

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, titlesec

I've search on many ways for this.

I want to quit the title toc bc the title format is working over it. I want a clear title in toc, but my format is affecting. I share my code next:

```
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\raggedleft\bfseries \Large \scshape}{}{1pt}{  
  \begin{spacing}{0} %https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=993
  \parskip=0pt
  \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\ 
  \vspace{5pt}
  SECCIÓN \\
  \vspace{5pt}
  \thesection \\
  \vspace{7pt}
  \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
  \end{spacing}
  \vspace{25pt}
  }[]
```

Next to begin the document, i have:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
```

So, at present the result that I want to avoid, there is no TOC as itself, just a section counting:

[My page with the title format without the toc title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKsOq.png)]

Comment: You should define another format with `\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}…`

Comment: Respond as a answer, just to help the format here. Thanks! I didn't thought that!

Answer (score 1):

As the table of contents is an unnumbered section in the article class, you can specify the formatting of all unnumbered sections  with the dedicated key:

`\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[style]{}{0pt}{…}`.

Comment: Precisely that modification was needed, the numberless. I found in documentation is necesary to put `name=\section, numberless` as a separator. The one give more complications was the explicit in options of titlesec, it have be there as the post i found [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102116/titlesec-and-section-in-titleformat), and of course, the documentation explains it.  My titleformat for the numbered sections needs a modification, and it had solved with this post [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361723/section-title-disappears-when-using-titlesec)

Comment: Fine! Anyway, one should always read the documentation, not just skim through them·

Answer (score 0):

Solution founded!

Simple share the code, note the format to define titleformat by explicit form.

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\raggedleft\bfseries \Large \scshape}{  
  \begin{spacing}{0} %https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=993
  \parskip=0pt
  \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\ 
  \vspace{5pt}
  SECCIÓN \\
  \vspace{5pt}
  \thesection \\
  \vspace{7pt}
  \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
  \end{spacing}
  \vspace*{-20pt}
  }{3pt}{#1}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[display]{\Huge\scshape\centering}{}{1pt}{#1}
```

Here is the results:

[image]

[image]

One of the post I use was of 6 years ago, and the other from 4 years. It is amazing to think resources like this great page still helping and the way to do it.

The links was:

1. Found how to select numberless sections.
   [titlesec and \section* in \titleformat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102116/titlesec-and-section-in-titleformat)
2. As the explicit mode was needed, I have to change the numbered sections.
   [Section title disappears when using titlesec?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361723/section-title-disappears-when-using-titlesec)